# i am using quickblox sdk v 2.0f for chat/audio/video call in our app &facing issue that when app runs in background user will not get calls

Tags: android, ios, quickblox

We are using `qucikblox sdk 2.0` in online consultation mobile application in both `platform ios & android`.  But recently facing issue that if A user device is locked or A user is not using app and if B user calls A user over audio/video A user will not get call.

1. Case 1-- Device locked app is in foreground  User A will be getting a call from user B but user A will not get to know about a call when user A unlock device then only user A can see call notification.
2. Case 2-- App is in background & device is unlocked  User A will not get a audio.video call, evn push message of chats also not receiving

Answer (score 0):

Create a sticky service which will run in background even activity destroy, this service is responsible for QBsession and all other operations so it will detect call in background so you will create Session in service , not in CallActivity. Iam successfully implements this and iam successfully receiving calls in background by this.

```
public class BloxService extends Service implements QBRTCClientSessionCallbacks {
    private QBChatService chatService;
    private volatile boolean resultReceived = true;
    static final String APP_ID = "";
    static final String AUTH_KEY = "";
    static final String AUTH_SECRET = "";
    static final String ACCOUNT_KEY = "";
    private QBRTCClient rtcClient;
    public static BloxService bloxService;
    private static final String TAG = "BloxService";
    public boolean isSessionRunning;
    public boolean isCallRunning;
    private  Date tokenExpirationDate;
    private QBAuth qbAuth;
    private AppPrefs prefs;

    private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            /*boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
            boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);*/
            NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            //NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);
            if(currentNetworkInfo!=null && currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()){
                if(!QBChatService.getInstance().isLoggedIn()){
                    if(!isSessionRunning) {
                        initializeQb();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
       // prefs = AppPrefs.getInstance(getApplicationContext()); // for testing we put this line on start
        registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("bloxservice","onDestroy");
        try{
            unregisterReceiver(mConnReceiver);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        prefs = AppPrefs.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        if (prefs.getData(IS_USER_LOGIN, false)) {
            Log.d("bloxservice","start");
            try {
                if (!QBChatService.getInstance().isLoggedIn()) {
                    initializeQb();
                }
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                initializeQb();
            }
            bloxService=this;
        }
        else {
            stopSelf();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public static BloxService getBloxService() {
        return bloxService;
    }

    public void initializeQb(){
        QBSettings.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext(), APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
        QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(ACCOUNT_KEY);
        QBChatService.setDebugEnabled(true);
// added on 20 july
        QBChatService.setDefaultAutoSendPresenceInterval(60);
        QBChatService.ConfigurationBuilder chatServiceConfigurationBuilder = new QBChatService.ConfigurationBuilder();
        chatServiceConfigurationBuilder.setSocketTimeout(60); //Sets chat socket's read timeout in seconds
        chatServiceConfigurationBuilder.setKeepAlive(true); //Sets connection socket's keepAlive option.
        QBChatService.setConfigurationBuilder(chatServiceConfigurationBuilder);
    //    QBChatService.getInstance().startAutoSendPresence(10);// added on 20 july
        chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();

       /* tokenExpirationDate = qbAuth.getTokenExpirationDate();
        try {
          String Token=  QBAuth.getSession().toString();
            QBAuth.createFromExistentToken()
        } catch (QBResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
*/
        if(AppPrefs.getInstance(this).getData(Constants.PrefsConstatnt.IS_USER_LOGIN,false)){
            Log.e("Login Process", "Started");
            isSessionRunning=true;
            String userId=AppPrefs.getInstance(this).getData(Constants.PrefsConstatnt.USER_ID,"");
            String name=AppPrefs.getInstance(this).getData(Constants.PrefsConstatnt.USER_NAME,"");
            String picUrl=AppPrefs.getInstance(this).getData(Constants.PrefsConstatnt.USER_IMAGE,"");
            String phone=prefs.getData(Constants.PrefsConstatnt.USER_PHONE, "");
            if(name.isEmpty()){
                name=userId;
            }
            createAppSession(Integer.parseInt(userId)<10?"0"+userId:userId,name,userId,picUrl,phone);
        }
    }

    private void createAppSession(final String userId, final String name,final String exId,final String picUrl,final String phone) {
        QBAuth.createSession(new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession qbSession, Bundle bundle) {
                loadUsers(userId, name, exId,picUrl,phone);
                final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
                if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
                }

                // Subscribe to Push Notifications
                //subscribeToPushNotifications(registrationId);


            }
            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
                isSessionRunning=false;
            }
        });
    }
    //QBUser users;
    public void loadUsers(String userId,String name,String exId,String picUrl,String phone) {
        final QBUser userr = new QBUser(userId, DataHolder.PASSWORD);
        userr.setFullName(name);
        userr.setExternalId(exId);
        userr.setCustomData(picUrl);
        userr.setPhone(phone);
        QBUsers.signUp(userr, new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle args) {
                createSession(userr.getLogin(), userr.getPassword());

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                QBUsers.signIn(userr, new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle args) {
                        createSession(userr.getLogin(), userr.getPassword());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(QBResponseException error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                        isSessionRunning = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    private void createSession(final String login, final String password) {
        final QBUser user = new QBUser(login, password);
        QBAuth.createSession(login, password, new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession session, Bundle bundle) {
                user.setId(session.getUserId());
                Log.e("User" + session.getUserId(), "Login");
                QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
                sendRegistrationToServer(AppPrefs.getInstance(BloxService.this).getData(Constants.PrefsConstatnt.DEVICE_TOKEN, ""));
                DataHolder.setLoggedUser(user);
                if (chatService.isLoggedIn()) {
                    resultReceived = true;
                    initQBRTCClient();
                    isSessionRunning = false;
                } else {
                    chatService.login(user, new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void result, Bundle bundle) {
                            initQBRTCClient();
                            resultReceived = true;
                            isSessionRunning = false;
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError(QBResponseException exc) {
                            resultReceived = true;
                            isSessionRunning = false;
                        }
                    });
                }

/*                QBRosterListener rosterListener = new QBRosterListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void entriesDeleted(Collection<Integer> userIds) {
                        Log.d("mayanks","changed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void entriesAdded(Collection<Integer> userIds) {
                        Log.d("mayanks","changed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void entriesUpdated(Collection<Integer> userIds) {
                        Log.d("mayanks","changed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void presenceChanged(QBPresence presence) {
                        Log.d("mayanks","changed");
                    }
                };

                QBSubscriptionListener subscriptionListener = new QBSubscriptionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void subscriptionRequested(int userId) {

                    }
                };

                QBRoster chatRoster = QBChatService.getInstance().getRoster(QBRoster.SubscriptionMode.mutual, subscriptionListener);
                chatRoster.addRosterListener(rosterListener);
                Collection<QBRosterEntry> entries = chatRoster.getEntries();
                QBPresence presence = chatRoster.getPresence(9);
                if (presence!=null) {

                    if (presence.getType() == QBPresence.Type.online) {
                        Log.d("mayanks","online");
                        // User is online
                    }else{
                        Log.d("mayanks","offline");
                        // User is offline
                    }
                }*/

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException exc) {
                resultReceived = true;
                isSessionRunning = false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                String deviceID = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_DEVICE_ID, null);
                if(deviceID==null)
                {
                    deviceID=DeviceUtils.getDeviceUid();
                    storeDeviceId(getApplicationContext(),deviceID);
                }
                QBSubscription qbSubscription = new QBSubscription();
                qbSubscription.setNotificationChannel(QBNotificationChannel.GCM);
                qbSubscription.setDeviceUdid(deviceID);
                qbSubscription.setRegistrationID(token);
                qbSubscription.setEnvironment(QBEnvironment.DEVELOPMENT); // Don't forget to change QBEnvironment to PRODUCTION when releasing application
                QBPushNotifications.createSubscription(qbSubscription,
                        new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBSubscription>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBSubscription> qbSubscriptions, Bundle bundle) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Successfully subscribed for QB push messages");
                                //saveGcmRegIdToPreferences(gcmRegId);
                                isSessionRunning=false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(QBResponseException error) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to subscribe for QB push messages; " + error.toString());
                                isSessionRunning=false;
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveNewSession(final QBRTCSession qbrtcSession) {
        Log.d("bloxservice","CallRecive");
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(!isCallRunning) {
                    DataHolder.incomingSession = qbrtcSession;
                   /* Map<String,String> userInfo = qbrtcSession.getUserInfo();
                    String s=userInfo.get("mayank");*/
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BloxService.this, CallActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("incoming", true);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else{
                    Log.e("User","Busy");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserNotAnswer(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer) {
       // ToastUtil.showShortToast(this, "no answer");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallRejectByUser(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer, Map<String, String> map) {
      //  ToastUtil.showShortToast(this,"rejected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallAcceptByUser(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer, Map<String, String> map) {
        //ToastUtil.showShortToast(this,"accepted");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveHangUpFromUser(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer, Map<String, String> map) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUserNoActions(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer) {
       // ToastUtil.showShortToast(this,"no Action");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionClosed(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession) {
       // ToastUtil.showShortToast(this,"onSessionClosed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionStartClose(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession) {
       // ToastUtil.showShortToast(this,"onSessionStartClose");
    }

    private void initQBRTCClient() {
        rtcClient = QBRTCClient.getInstance(this);
        QBVideoChatWebRTCSignalingManager qbChatService = QBChatService.getInstance().getVideoChatWebRTCSignalingManager();
        if (qbChatService != null) {
            qbChatService.addSignalingManagerListener(new QBVideoChatSignalingManagerListener() {
                @Override
                public void signalingCreated(QBSignaling qbSignaling, boolean createdLocally) {
                    if (!createdLocally) {
                        rtcClient.addSignaling((QBWebRTCSignaling) qbSignaling);
                    }
                }
            });
            QBRTCConfig.setMaxOpponentsCount(2);
            QBRTCConfig.setDisconnectTime(40);
            QBRTCConfig.setAnswerTimeInterval(30l);
            QBRTCConfig.setDebugEnabled(true);

            rtcClient.addSessionCallbacksListener(this);
            rtcClient.prepareToProcessCalls();
            QBChatService.getInstance().addConnectionListener(new AbstractConnectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {

                }
                @Override
                public void reconnectionSuccessful() {

                }
                @Override
                public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void logout(){
        chatService.logout(new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void result, Bundle bundle) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException list) {
            }
        });
    }

/*    public void subscribeToPushNotifications(String registrationID) {
        QBSubscription subscription = new QBSubscription(QBNotificationChannel.GCM);
        subscription.setEnvironment(QBEnvironment.DEVELOPMENT);
        //
        String deviceId;
        final TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(
                Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null) {
            deviceId = mTelephony.getDeviceId(); /*//*** use for mobiles
        } else {
            deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID); /*//*** use for tablets
        }
        subscription.setDeviceUdid(deviceId);
        //
        subscription.setRegistrationID(registrationID);
        //
        QBPushNotifications.createSubscription(subscription, new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBSubscription>>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBSubscription> subscriptions, Bundle args) {
                Log.d("push_send","sucess");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException error) {
                Log.d("push_send","sucess");
            }
        });
    }*/
    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences,
        // but
        // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
        Log.e("getGCMPreferences", "package= " + context.getPackageName());
        return getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private void storeDeviceId(Context context, String deviceId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_DEVICE_ID, deviceId);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: hi mayank sharma....,can u send AppPrefs.java file .if have any source code.plz send to me .we also facing same issue
my mail id  kopperanaresh@gmail.com